# Debian partitions on an SD card - how to fix?

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

Here's the output of `sfdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 242560 cylinders, 4 heads, 16 sectors/track   
Units: cylinders of 32768 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0   

Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System   
/dev/mmcblk0p1         64    2111    2048      65536   83  Linux   
            start: (c,h,s) expected (64,0,1) found (0,65,2)   
            end: (c,h,s) expected (1023,3,16) found (8,105,33)   
/dev/mmcblk0p2       2112   45311   43200    1382400   83  Linux   
            start: (c,h,s) expected (1023,3,16) found (8,105,34)   
            end: (c,h,s) expected (1023,3,16) found (180,131,15)   
/dev/mmcblk0p3          0       -       0          0    0  Empty   
/dev/mmcblk0p4          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
```

When I run `parted` I'm told:

```
GNU Parted 3.2   
Using /dev/sr0   
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.   
(parted) p all   
Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 512 bytes, but Linux says it is 2048 bytes.   
Ignore/Cancel? i
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!
Ignore/Cancel? i
Model: T-Mobile USB SCSI CD-ROM (scsi)
Disk /dev/sr0: 7773kB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/2048B
Partition Table: mac
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                             Flags
 1      512B    18.4kB  17.9kB               MRKS
 2      67.6kB  31.1MB  31.0MB  hfs+         Toast 8.0.1 HFS+/Joliet Builder

Model: SD SU08G (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7948MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      2097kB  69.2MB  67.1MB  primary  fat16
 2      69.2MB  1485MB  1416MB  primary  ext4
```

My goal is to grow the root partition to fill the whole 8G card.. but I'm not sure how to clean up the current problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can read the data on the card, the *simplest* way to "clean up" the existing problems and grow the partition to fill the card will be to back up all files on the card, create a new partition table (using fdisk or a higher level partition editor), then create new partition(s) using all available space, format to your chosen file system(s), and copy the data back to the card.

If you *can't* read the data on the card, you'll need to start with something along the lines of `fsck` to (hopefully) become able to read the data, then proceed as above.  If `fsck` won't recover access to the file system, it's possible certain partition editors (the GUI version of GParted is one) can "rescue" the data, but this is likely to take a very long time because it requires a full-read raw bit pattern scan and analysis (I tried this once on a 4 GB USB stick, albeit on a very old computer, and it was still running without any progress indicator after two hours).

Comment: I have full access to the card. Were it not for wanting to use all of the available space I wouldn't have even known this problem exists.

Comment: Then you can most likely copy the contents of the first two partitions, repartition and reformat the card, and copy the data back in about twenty minutes -- half of which time you can spend doing short tasks in another window or away from the computer.